# Outlook API revoke authorization

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, outlook-restapi

I'm looking for a way to revoke APP authorization to an outlook account by API.

Something like this exist on google (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke)

Does anyone know a way to do that with Outlook ?